# Dynamic pivot with tweaks

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to solve experiment with some SQL pivoting. I have created a pivot by naming the columns, I am now trying to do it dynamically. From a few searches I have come up with the following code

```
USE [LMS]
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Learning_Path_Title)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Learning_Path_Title] FROM [dbo].[copy from]) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Distinct [Userd], ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM [dbo].[copy from]
    PIVOT(MAX([Learning_Path_Complete]) 
          FOR [Learning_Path_Title] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

My data is structured in the following way

[image: Initial table]

I want the table to be displayed as below

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Please don't post images of data. If you are going to provide data take the time to format it as tabular `text` or do so as DDL and DML statements. The volunteers you're asking for help from can't use an image, and so are unlikely to use their *free* time to help you. Help us help you.

Comment: Also, what is your question here, you haven't asked one. What's wrong with the SQL you have?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, apologies the sql I have doesn’t group the learning path title by user it Results in multiple rows per user I will try to format the tables instead of the images I have provided first post on the forum so I struggled a bit getting the tables in